# api call for image and use it for base64

Tags: html, node.js, image, api, base64

Due to a site cross-issue on Safari reason regarding CORS, I cannot use URL directly to frontend

what I am doing is making an API call to the URL and converting it to base64 sending to frontend and using it there passing in

Unfortunately, It's not working as the image shows is broken, I suspect that it's due to some unknown reason.

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/325642177_505094921747710_9035707955179438711_n.webp?stp=dst-jpg&_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=hcMVLqiH044AX_O3sip&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&edm=AEoDcc0EAAAA&oh=00_AfDfXVcdc658NDViC2RvQDUbeZuvOhOl5M-xliFO9XfbdQ&oe=63C5998C

this is the image URL I am making API call

```
 const config = {
      method: "get",
      url,
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      headers: {},
    };

    const datares = await axios(config);

    let base64;
    base64 = Buffer.from(datares?.data).toString('base64');
    if (datares?.status !== 200) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        msg: datares?.data?.message || "Internal server error",
      });
    }
    // base64 with img according to the url
    const accpbase64 = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`;
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: accpbase64,
      msg: "base64 retrieved successfully",
    });
```

This is the API call response and below is the header of response

```
{
  'x-storage-error-category': 'dfs:none;hs_p:200:HS_ESUCCESS',
  'last-modified': 'Fri, 13 Jan 2023 14:04:31 GMT',
  'x-haystack-needlechecksum': '2479215415',
  'x-needle-checksum': '3312581816',
  'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
  'content-digest': 'adler32=3360421242',
  'timing-allow-origin': '*',
  'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'cross-origin',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=1209600, no-transform',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  'x-fb-trip-id': '2141700578',
  date: 'Fri, 13 Jan 2023 17:46:19 GMT',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '112923'
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-farrell-3jb93m?file=/src/App.js

here's example response of base64 using as in  tag

Can someone help me here with this?

Comment: So what's the actual problem you're asking about? Is `datares` the wrong data (or null?) Is `base64` now what it's supposed to be? Does `accpbase64` not become what it should be? Does the network response not contain the data you need? Please remember to [focus on the one problem that you're having](/help/how-to-ask), and remember to show all details _in your post_ even if you link out: that link to app.js should be [mcve] code that shows how you're using the response on the client side. Links expire/die, SO posts should still make sense when they do.

Answer (score 0):

Your value in `accpbase64` works fine. You just need to use that value in the src of your image.

See demo with base64 of image you provided, https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-noyce-u0j0g1